# create trigger after update on

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have "users" database table with colum "session_id". I need to create trigger after update on users -> session_id changes. My code:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `map_stats` AFTER UPDATE ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `users_maps` WHERE `player_id` = NEW.`id` AND `session_id` = NEW.`session_id`)
    THEN
        UPDATE `users_maps` SET
```

Its working, but if user change some info, trigger also change. I need just if user session_id changed. Sorry for bad english, but i think u understand my problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like

```
IF NEW.session_id <> OLD. session_id
```

This ensures that that particular field was different after the update.